# What needs light but dies if it shines on it?

Tags: riddle

Strange riddle I came across;

> I can only live where there is light,
>
> but I die if the light shines on me.
>
> What am I?

What is the answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could you perhaps be

> A shadow?

Comment: Man I think that this is actually the answer, thank you!